# XSLT accessing child element to retrieve parent element

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Here is my following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>price</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="library/book/authors/author[first='Harry'and last='Potter'] ">

      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is my XSL stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>price</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="library/book/authors/author[first='Harry'and last='Potter'] ">

      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am unable to display title and price as they are the parent element and I'm giving condition to my child element. And I need to display information regarding my parents element.

Comment: both are xsl & the same. edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to a parent node in your XPath expression using "../".  For example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../title"/>
<xsl:value-of select="../../price"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd be inclined to suggest that you use a predicate so the `for-each` operates over the `book` elements instead of the `author` ones:

```
<xsl:for-each select="library/book[authors/author[first='Harry'and last='Potter']] ">
```

This says "select all the book elements that have at least one author named Harry Potter".